# Null pointer in Idris FFI

Tags: idris

How do I call a function with a NULL parameter of type FPtr with the Idris FFI?  I've looked through the library, and it looks like there's neither a null pointer nor a way to cast integers to pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a constant `null` in [`Prelude.Strings`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/44cdd8a8fe51a696addc365d4e52b574576654b0/libs/prelude/Prelude/Strings.idr#L67) (out of all places).  This was indicated to me by MaxOw on [the Idris bug tracker](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/1690).